# Options Menu Periodically causes App to Crash and Closes Last Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-optionsmenu

**Solution:** *So, after being stuck on this for quite a while, I finally discovered that the issue was because my activity was titled Menu. I guess this is a reserved word in some way or another and because of that, it would cause random crashes to occur when trying to start the intent `Menu::class.java`. I changed the name of the activity and everything works as expected now.*

I have added an Options Menu to an app that I am working on which contains a "home" button. The button works most of the time but periodically it causes the app to crash when it's clicked. It seems to happen after the button has already been clicked at least once and/or after the native back button has been pressed. Additionally, once the button is pressed, it seems to close the last activity. Clicking the back button after clicking the home button does not take me back to where I was. Below is my code for the toolbar.

```
// Creates toolbar
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    val menuInflater = menuInflater
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu)
    return true
}

// Listens to click of toolbar
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val id = item.itemId
    if (id == R.id.home) {
        val intent = Intent(this, Menu::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Here's the logcat:

> 2023-11-28 11:58:15.760  6693-6693  AndroidRuntime
> com.benwhittington.flanges           D  Shutting down VM 2023-11-28
> 11:58:15.765  6693-6693  AndroidRuntime
> com.benwhittington.flanges           E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.benwhittington.flanges, PID: 6693
> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
> activity class {com.benwhittington.flanges/android.view.Menu}; have
> you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your
> intent not match its declared ?
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2171)
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1805)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5596)
> at
> androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:780)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5554)
> at
> androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:761)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6052)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6019)
> at
> com.benwhittington.flanges.FlangeInspection.onOptionsItemSelected(FlangeInspection.kt:242)
> at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:4532)
> at
> androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ComponentActivity.java:528)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:352)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:269)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:110)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:66)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:225)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:781)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:836)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:159)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:987)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:977)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:625)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:156)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7892)
> at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16220)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7869)
> at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30891)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Flanges"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewISO"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewInspection"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AddEmail"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FlangeInspection"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SignUp"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after being stuck on this for quite a while, I finally discovered that the issue was because my activity was titled Menu. I guess this is a reserved word in some way or another and because of that, it would cause random crashes to occur when trying to start the intent Menu::class.java. I changed the name of the activity and everything works as expected now.

Comment: Your recent contribution seems better suited as a comment rather than a standalone answer. Please consider adding it as a comment to the relevant post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error occurs because even though you have Menu activity declared in your Android Manifest, it seems you have Menu Activity nested in folders, so, you have to add to your Android Manifest the entire route (I belive is android.view.Menu)

Your code:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:exported="false" />
```

New code:

```
<activity
    android:name=".android.view.Menu"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, this wasn't the issue. I was able to figure it out and have edited my original post to show the solution.

Comment: I'm glad you could figure out the problem, happy coding!